# How do I properly do API calls usin Nuxt 3 Generate method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

As the title suggests, whenever I perform a search in production using `npm run generate`, I get a 404 response for the search API

I have the following structure

```
pages/search/index.vue
```

and

```
server/api/search/index.ts
```

I also have other routes which work perfectly, but the search is dynamic according to the query that is passed through.

In `dev` and `build` mode everything works perfectly fine but when using `npm run generate` I get a `FetchError: [POST] "/api/search": 404 Not Found` whenever I perform a new search. I suspect the `server` folder isn't available after generating everything. The search page is available and renders fine.

This is the method I use to search

```
const getSearchResults = async (q: LocationQueryValue | LocationQueryValue[]): Promise<SearchResults> => {
  const response: SearchResults = await $fetch('/api/search', {
    method: 'post',
    body: {
      q,
    },
  })

  return response
}
```

I understand that static sites work a bit differently but I'm struggling to find an optimal solution to this. A guide to setting up a search would be amazing!